# Swapping divs around depending on screen size

Tags: jquery

I am working on a responsive site, although i cant really change the HTML around, just the CSS and JS.

I have a grid of fixtures, and when the screen size get to 480px i want to move a div to below another div.

To see the problem, view this demo i set up http://jsfiddle.net/FyXRU/

My Code is

```
<div class="fixture">
    <div class="fixture-date">Date</div>

    <div class="teams">Teams</div>

    <div class="details">Detials</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="fixture">
    <div class="fixture-date">Date</div>

    <div class="teams">Teams</div>

    <div class="details">Detials</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="fixture">
    <div class="fixture-date">Date</div>

    <div class="teams">Teams</div>

    <div class="details">Detials</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="fixture">
    <div class="fixture-date">Date</div>

    <div class="teams">Teams</div>

    <div class="details">Detials</div>
</div>



$(window).resize(function() { //Fires when window is resized
    iTargetWidth = $(window).width();

    if (iTargetWidth < 770) { 
        $("div.fixture-date").insertAfter("div.teams");
    }
});
```

what im after is moving the date after the teams div.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I don't know your css file, but using media queries you could float `teams` to left and `fixture-date` will have to go after the float. All can be done from css alone.

Comment: the items will be 100% width so that wouldn't really work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() { //Fires when window is resized
    var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if(width <= 770) {
        $(".fixture").each(function() {
        var detach = $(this).find(".fixture-date").detach();
        $(detach).insertAfter($(this).find(".teams"));
        })
    }
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/FyXRU/2/)

Comment: Works a treat. Spot on mate. Thank you very much